# Not getting values from inputs in the submit form without permission popup browser

Tags: php, forms, symfony, popup, submit

I got a weird error when trying to submit a form.

The first time I submit this form my browser asks me for adding the url I'm using to the "allowed url list" to be able to execute a pop-up automatically.

When I accept to allow executing pop-ups from this url, finally executes automatically the url destination from the form but my input values are not sent.

Once the url is already inside the list of permissions, this problem does not repeat again but obviously I would like to fix this first access when the url still not registered to the list of permissions from the browser to execute pop-up.

I need in all cases to get the input values from the form as normally does.

The process will be made by an ajax, a form and a controller.

When I click my button action I send the info I need via AJAX to the controller to set up a file in my app. Until here is all ok. After that, I submit the form in a new tab from the browser and the controller who handles this form make the browser ask me for adding the url to the **allowed websites from the browser to be able to execute a pop-up** (in this case is a pop up for downloading the previous file I made on the AJAX).

[image]

I know that I don't receive any value because I have a part of code to handle the validations and I receive the email with no values from the inputs.

JQuery - Ajax:

```
$('#downloadZip').click(function () {

        ...

        var $data = JSON.parse('{ "tipoT...": "'+$tipoT...+'",etc }');

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('urldestination') }}",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $data
        });

        request.done(function (response){
            if (response !== "Error") {
                $("#valueIneedFromAjaxInsideFormToExecute ").val(response);
                $("#formToExecute").submit();
            } else {
                alert('{{ 'error'|trans }}');
            }
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            ....
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<form action="{{ path('download_zip') }}" id='formToExecute' target='_blank' method='post'>
    <input name='input1' id='valueIneedFromAjaxInsideFormToExecute' value='' style='display: none;'>
</form>
```

Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("xxxx", name="download_zip")
 * @Security("is_granted('xx_xxx') or is_granted('xx_xxxx')")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
 * @param FieldsValidation $fieldsValidation
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function downloadZipAction(Request $request, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, FieldsValidation $fieldsValidation)
{
    $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $xxx = $user->getxxx();
    $xxxUser = $user->getxxxx();

    if ($request->get("input1") !== null && $fieldsValidation->validateInput1((int)$request->get("input1"))) {
        $input1 = $request->get("input1");
    } else {
        $errorException = new ErrorException($this->generateUrl('error',
            [
                'errorThrown' => 'input1 introduced is not passing the validation',
                'errorData' => $request->get("input1"),
                'errorOrigin' => 'downloadZipAction'
            ]
        ));
        return $this->redirect($errorException->redirectResponse);
    }

    $dirPath = '.../var/cache/files/'.$xxx.'-'.$xxxUser;
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private"); // required for certain browsers
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='documentos-".$input1.".zip'");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($dirPath . '/documentos-'.$input1.".zip"));
    readfile($dirPath.'/documentsZip-'.$input1.".zip");

    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files AS $key => $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($dirPath);
    die;
}
```